# Proving a particular subset of a Hilbert space is a subspace

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have a small question please, how to prove that this set:

$F=\lbrace h\in H, \langle f''(u)h,h\rangle <0\rbrace$ is a sub space of the Hilbert space $H$, where $f''(u)$ is a self-adjoint operator from $H$ to $ H$

I calculated $\langle f''(u)(\lambda h+\mu k),(\lambda h+\mu k) \rangle= \langle \lambda f''(u) h,\lambda h\rangle +\langle \lambda f''(u) h,\mu k\rangle+ \langle \mu f''(u) k,\lambda h\rangle + \langle \mu f''(u) k,\mu k\rangle$
But i don't know how to say that  $\langle \lambda f''(u) h,\mu k\rangle <0$ and  $\langle\mu f''(u) k,\lambda h \rangle <0 $

please thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is not a subspace.  If your operator is positive definite, then $F$ is empty. More generally,  your $F$ cannot contain $h=0$, so it will not be a subspace for any choice of an operator, selfadjoint or not.

Even if you replace $<$ with $\leq$, it will still not be a subspace in general: consider the operator $T=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$. For $h=(x,y) $ you have
$$
\langle Th,h\rangle=\left\langle\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle=2xy.
$$
So $(2,-1)$ and $(-1,2)$ are in $F$, while $(2,-1)+(-1,2)=(1,1)$, not in $F$.

Comment: The operator is negative defined, the $F$ represent $H_-$ the space where $f''(p)$ is negative defined if it is not a subspace then we don't have this decomposition $H=H_-\oplus H_+$ ?

Comment: if i write $\langle f''(u)h,h\rangle \leq 0$ it is a subspace ?

Comment: To your second question, I gave you a counterexample above. If the operator is negative-defined, then I don't see what decomposition you want to make.  If the operator has negative eigenvalues, their eigenvectors will satisfy yoyr inequality; but doesn't make all operators satisfying the inequality a subspace.